# Setting user status to offline on logout (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to add a query update to my `logout.php`.  I'm not understanding why the following doesn't update the dB.

```
global $con;
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$setOfflineStatus = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET status='offline' WHERE username='$username'");

session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: ../../register.php")
```

Once they log in, I have the reverse of this running and it updates the status to online.  works fine.

The logout button is:

```
<a href="includes/handlers/logout.php"><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried manually running `SELECT users WHERE username='<username>'` to make sure your query is working correctly?

Comment: Hi Derek, I haven't tried this no.  It's hard to know b/c logout.php redirects to register.php.  All I know is that when I refresh phpmyadmin the status is still online after logout.  The above query works on login.php (in reverse) so I don't see why the reverse on logout wouldn't connect.

Comment: Just try running that command in PHP admin to see if your update query is selecting the right document.

Comment: There may be a session problem you have started your session at end. You need to start your session in beginning of your page.

Comment: Got it to work :)  Thanks for the suggestions.  I just changed: $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  to: $userLoggedIn = $_SESSION['username']; made the adjustment in the query & it fired. I forgot that I re-declared the session variable in header.php.